# Highlighting a row in EXCEL if one cell is blank

Tags: excel

I am working on a project to determine which stock broker companies I need to create a pricing list for. I have 2 sources of data. The first is a laundry list of brokers, many of which are not needed. This list also has the pricing for each product. The second source of data is a list of 6 months worth of executed stock trades, and their associated brokers. The second source is most valuable because these are the only brokers we've used in the last 6 months, so it's assumed these will be a bulk of the pricing list.

The issue is, both sources of data have different naming conventions, some using acronyms, so there is no easy way to line up the corresponding companies from both data sets. What I've created so far is 2 columns, one with data source one, and one with data source two next to it. I've painstakingly gone down the lists, matched the broker that correspond from both lists by putting them next to each other (reconciliation). So now, the brokers that match from both lists are next to each other, but the ones that don't have an empty cell next to them and require further investigation.

What I want to do, through use of a formula/conditional formatting, is highlight the rows that have brokers that match (line up next to each other) in green and highlight the row where there is no corresponding broker in red, so that I can narrow the breaks down and further investigate.

I'm new to excel, but was trying to figure out a formula that may say something along the lines of, if there is a value in A and B, highlight green and if there is no value in A or B, highlight red.

**EDIT** After a little digging, I found out how to turn the row red where there is a blank cell in the row.

Conditional formatting > new rule > use formula > add formula:

=OR($A1="",B1="")

Now I need to find out how to implement a similar formula for cells that both have a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the same thing again with the below formula,

`=AND($A1<>"",B1<>"")`

and choose a color.